# How do I specify a Class variable that contains a generic

Tags: java, generics

Here's a sample that should explain my problem:

```
public class Scratch {
    public <T> Set<T> method(Class<T> clazz){return null;}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scratch s=new Scratch();
        Set<List<String>> list=s.method(List.class); //Gives error here.  How do I say List<String>.class?
    }
}
```

I really want to say `List<String>.class` for the clazz variable above, but that not the appropriate syntax.  Am I just using generics in a wrong way?

Comment: You cannot do that because of type erasure: all generics are "dimissed" at run time, and the run time class of `List<Whatever>` is always `List`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a limitation of the language and the standard library.

Workaround is to simply cast it brutely

```
(Class<List<String>>)(Class)List.class
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution.  Why does `(Class<List<String>>)List.class` not work but `(Class<List<String>>)(Class)List.class` works?

Comment: @User1: because `Foo<A>` will never be compatible with `Foo<B>` if A and B are different types

Comment: or to avoid raw types, use `(Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)List.class`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Class<?> clazz` worked.

Here's the modified code:

```
public class Scratch {
    public <T> Set<T> method(Class<?> clazz){return null;}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scratch s=new Scratch();
        Set<List<String>> list=s.method(List.class); 
        Set<Map<String,String>> map=s.method(Map.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Traroth for pushing me in the right direction.  I modified his answer to support a truly generic structure beyond just Lists.

EDIT:  I'm still not completely happy with the answer above because you can do something bad.  Consider this example:

```
public class Scratch {
    public <T> Set<T> method(Class<?> clazz){return null;}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scratch s=new Scratch();
        Set<List<String>> list=s.method(Map.class); //Should've passed List.class, but the compiler doesn't care.
        Set<Map<String,String>> map=s.method(Map.class);
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and I will likely get some runtime errors (depending on my implementation).  Any other advice is appreciated...